# Activation email to change admin address not being sent to Gsuite email account

Tags: email, activation

I changed my admin email in the WordPress dashboard I'm using to create a website and it's just not sending out the email to confirm changes. The domain is hosted through BlueHost and the domain email I'm trying to use is at a Gsuite account.

I'm trying to set up plugins and they are asking for my email so before I set up too many features I want to get my email updated. I keep seeing: "If you change this, we will send you an email at your new address to confirm it. The new address will not become active until confirmed. There is a pending change of your email to empathyheals@empathyminecraft.com."

No email ever came through and no, it's not in the spam folder. I also went to https://wordpress.com/support/contact/ and tried to use the Resend Activation Email feature under "Trouble Activating?" but when I click on Resend Activation nothing happens.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing and setting up the [WP Mail SMTP Plugin](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/#create-app)

Answer (score 0):

I have relatively less knowledge range of this topic hope my case from yesterday can provide you with some little hint.

In my case the verification email did come through in a minute as,
from: WordPress wordpress@mydomain.com via netorgft680****.onmicrosoft.com

And I am using GoDaddy/Installatron to deploy my WP sites where if it is an email sent via host internal mail service it should be via *****.secureserver.net as per service operated by GoDaddy.

The WordPress verification email is clearly not from my host mail server as it is from some Microsoft O365 based service.